# Appearing div classes with css transitions?

Tags: css, animation, fade, transition

So... I have three div classes inside a slide in a carrousel.
Right now I have a display:none for the normal elements and display:block for the elements with .current class like this:

```
p.readmore,.logo,.slidetxt{
display: none;
}


.current p.readmore, .current .logo, .current .slidetxt{
display: block;
}
```

It works but it just "pops" in and I'd like to fade the appearance.
I also have a title that moves down when in current and I'd like to animate or fadeout-in that one too.

```
.current h1.carousel-title{
margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this css styling to the current class. I would recomend that you used opacity instead of display to toggle the exibition of the slides.

```
.slide { opacity: 0; }

.slide.current {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; 
    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     
    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0;       
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1.1);  
    }
    80% {
        transform: scale(0.9);
        opacity: 1; 
    }   
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1; 
    }       
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0.0;       
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
        opacity: 1; 
    }   
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks! I removed the scale transform tho, I just needed the opacity ones :)

Comment: This site have a lot of pre-built animations, it's very usefull: http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery?

If so there are a few animations that are built in to it and can be found at the following link:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

If you are not using jQuery here is a CSS3 HTML5 animation demo:

http://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-fade-slider/